# How to divide the returned documents into a fix number of buckets in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-net

I have a question that I thought was simple to google but I couldn't find an answer.

I have an index of articles with an optional field `price` among the many.

I'd like to create an aggregation that divides all the articles matching the query in buckets that match these properties:

- a bucket for all items with `price = 0`
- a fixed number of buckets for all the items with `price > 0` (say 10), possibly with a range included.

To give an idea of the ideal result, given a search returning items with prices ranging from 0 to 2000, the result of the aggregation could be something like:

```json
[
   {"from": 0, "to": 0, "doc_count": 100},
   {"from": 1, "to": 200, "doc_count": 23},
   {"from": 201, "to": 400, "doc_count": 11},
   {"from": 401, "to": 600, "doc_count": 23},
   {"from": 601, "to": 800, "doc_count": 120},
   {"from": 801, "to": 1000, "doc_count": 1100},
   {"from": 1001, "to": 1200, "doc_count": 25},
   {"from": 1201, "to": 1400, "doc_count": 12},
   {"from": 1401, "to": 1600, "doc_count": 24},
   {"from": 1601, "to": 1800, "doc_count": 42},
   {"from": 1801, "to": 2000, "doc_count": 52}
]
```

I have looked into `histogram` aggregation but it focuses on fixed intervals rather than fixed amount of buckets and I couldn't find a way to isolate the items with `price = 0`.

```json
{
  "aggs": {
    "price": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "price",
        "interval": 2500.0
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

With some backend processing I was able to obtain the following result

```json
[
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 0,
      "To": 2499
    },
    "Items": 139
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 2500,
      "To": 4999
    },
    "Items": 17
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 5000,
      "To": 7499
    },
    "Items": 7
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 7500,
      "To": 9999
    },
    "Items": 2
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 10000,
      "To": 12499
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 12500,
      "To": 14999
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 15000,
      "To": 17499
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 17500,
      "To": 19999
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 20000,
      "To": 22499
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 22500,
      "To": 24999
    },
    "Items": 2
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 25000,
      "To": 27499
    },
    "Items": 2
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 27500,
      "To": 29999
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 30000,
      "To": 32499
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 32500,
      "To": 34999
    },
    "Items": 2
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 35000,
      "To": 37499
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 37500,
      "To": 39999
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 40000,
      "To": 42499
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 42500,
      "To": 44999
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 45000,
      "To": 47499
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 47500,
      "To": 49999
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 50000,
      "To": 52499
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 52500,
      "To": 54999
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 55000,
      "To": 57499
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 57500,
      "To": 59999
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 60000,
      "To": 62499
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 62500,
      "To": 64999
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 65000,
      "To": 67499
    },
    "Items": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 67500,
      "To": 69999
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 70000,
      "To": 72499
    },
    "Items": 0
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 72500,
      "To": 74999
    },
    "Items": 2
  },
  {
    "Key": {
      "From": 75000,
      "To": null
    },
    "Items": 1
  }
]
```

I also have discarded using the `range` aggregation as it requires the definition of well-defined buckets by their boundaries.

I hope I gave enough context about what I am trying to achieve and what I attempted.

Thanks.

EDIT: added paragraph about `range` aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Range aggregation will allow you to create price ranges and so you will have a controlled limit of buckets you want

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "price": {
      "range": {
        "field": "price",
        "ranges": [
          { "from": 0.0, "to": 1.0 },
          { "from": 1.0, "to": 10.0 },
          { "from": 10.0, "to": 20.0 },
          { "from": 20.0 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }, 
  "size": 0
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, `range` aggregations require that the bucket boundaries are defined in the query. I am looking for something more dynamic.